New MS Teams - Deeplink from Adaptive Card to app tab removes the "Activity" tab from App
I am trying to create a deeplink to a tab for my MS teams app, the deeplink works like https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<APP_ID>/<TAB_ENTITY_ID>. I am using this link for generating the deeplink.
I am opening the deeplink through an adaptive card button from the bot conversation. The deeplink redirects me to the tab successfully but it removes the activity tab afterwards. After changing to another tab or refreshing the link, the Teams app closes and the install dialog of the app appears.
Tried on the classic teams and new teams. Realized the problem only occurs on the new version of the Teams client.

Are you using internal app id or external app id for navigation using deeplink?

@Vaibhav-MSFT im using the external app id. Can you tell me how to get the internal app id?

You can get both internal and external app id from Teams admin portal from Manage apps section.
